# MS Outlook change subject line of all drafts

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to change the subject line of 1000s of emails in my drafts.

Here is the code I'm using but it's not changing the subject line. Could someone please let me know what I'm missing.

```
Sub Drafts_Send()

Dim objDrafts As Outlook.Items
Dim objDraft As Object
Dim strPrompt As String
Dim nResponse As Integer
Dim i As Long

Set objDrafts = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts).Items

For i = objDrafts.Count To 1 Step -1
    If objDrafts.Item(i).Subject = "Please Thank You" Then
        objDrafts.Item(i).Subject = "Please & Thank You"
        objDrafts.Item(i).Save
    End If
Next i

Set objDrafts = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Edit your question to replace "not working" with useful information. What do you see when you debug?

Comment: sorry @niton, edited. there is no bug, it just simply does not change the subject line as expected.

Comment: When debugging by keying F8 in the editor, do you get to the `objDrafts.Item(i).Save` line?

Comment: @niton yes, it is recognized

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the default Drafts folder is not the folder containing the drafts you wish to update.

Run this macro:

```
Sub DsplStoreContainingfDefaultDrafts()

  Dim NS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim DefaultInboxFldr As MAPIFolder

  Set NS = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set DefaultInboxFldr = NS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)

  Debug.Print "Default Drafts folder in """ & DefaultInboxFldr.Parent.Name & """"

End Sub
```

On my system it outputs:

`Default Drafts folder in "Outlook Data File"`

“Outlook Data File” is the default store that came with the installation but it is only used for information not associated with an email account.  Outlook has created a separate store for each of my email accounts with names like JohnSmith@AcmeIsp.com and JohnSmith@gmail.com.  Each of those stores has its own Drafts folder and drafts are in the Drafts folder of the account from which I will send the email.

Go to the folder containing the drafts you wish to update.  Is it within the store identified by my macro?  If not continue reading.

The complication is that on my system, Drafts is a top level folder in the store for my regular ISP account but a second level folder in folder for my gmail account.

You will need to replace:

```
Set objDrafts = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts).Items
```

`Outlook.Application.` is redundant since you are running this within Outlook.

If you store is like my regular ISP account, you will need something like:

```
Set objDrafts = Session.Folders("JohnSmith@AcmeIsp.com").Folders("Drafts").Items
```

If you store is like my gmail account, you will need something like:

```
Set objDrafts = Session.Folders("JohnSmith@gmail.com").Folders("[Gmail]").Folders("Drafts").Items
```

Comment: Thanks, @tony dallimore! I tested my code before posting - it finds the records, it just doesn't change the subject line. But I tried your suggestion just in case - it finds the records as well but still does not change the subject line. With my original code and yours I'm able to mark read\unread, send, display - just not change the subject line. Seems very odd!!

Answer (score 0):

There are some tricks you can try.
`.DoEvents`, `.GetInspector` and as a last resort `.Display`.

```vb
Sub Drafts_Send()

Dim objDrafts As Items
Dim objDraft As Object
Dim i As Long

Set objDrafts = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts).Items

For i = objDrafts.Count To 1 Step -1

    If objDrafts.Item(i).Class = olMail Then
    
        Set objDraft = objDrafts.Item(i)
        
        With objDraft
         
            If .Subject = "Please Thank You" Then
    
                ' this has some .Display behaviour, without displaying
                .GetInspector
                '.Display ' as a last resort
        
                objDrafts.Item(i).Subject = "Please & Thank You"
                
                DoEvents
                
                ' if in Draft folder reading pane should be off
                .Save
            
            End If
            
        End With
        
        Set objDraft = Nothing
        
    End If
Next

Set objDrafts = Nothing

End Sub
```